# Method is not return correct value

Tags: php, oop

I am breaking my head over this problem the whole day already, and I cant figure it out why my code is behaving like this. I am using PDO to get data from the database and when I `var_dump` the `$stmt->fetchAll()` I get the expected results(an array with 2 objects) but when I call the method and `var_dump` it the result is the object that calls the method.

The user class derives from the ORM class

The code is as follows:

In index.php

`User::find(1);`

---

In ORM.php

```
protected static $table_name;
private $query;

public function __construct()
{
  $this->query = new Query(static::$table_name);
}


public static function find($id, $columns = "*")
{
  $user = User::get($columns, get_called_class(), PDO::FETCH_CLASS);
  return $user;
}

public static function findAll($columns = "*")
{
  return User::get($columns);
}

/**
 * Magic method to call methods
 */
public function __call($method, $args = array())
{
call_user_func_array( array( $this->query, $method ), $args);
return $this;
}

/**
 * Magic method to call static methods
 */
public static function __callStatic($method, $args = array())
{
  $static = new static;
  call_user_func_array( array( $static->query, $method ), $args);
  return $static;
```

}

---

and in Query.php

```
 public function get($columns = "*", $class_name = "", $fetch_mode = PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)      
{
   $stm = DB::prepare("select * from user");//the DB class is working properly
   $stm->execute();
   $fetch = $stm->fetchAll();
   var_dump($fetch); // This prints the correct array with 2 users in it
   return $fetch; // doesnt return somehow

}
```

Thanks in advance I have no idea how to fix this, as I am looking at this problem for the entire day already

Comment: Could you paste the output of both var_dump and return ? maybe the var_dump has more data but without seeing the two I couldn't say.

Comment: `get` is not defined as static but you're calling as `User::get` which is a static call.

Comment: @MathewFoscarini `get` is called via the `_callStatic` or `_call` method in ORM.php which uses the $query variable.

Comment: @OliverBS The var_dump is indeed a different object. Which is weird because as far as I am away should not be the case. Because the return  object of the `get` method

Comment: Could you paste the two outputs ? maybe and this is a long shot you have a object within an object maybe a hasMany, ManyOne, belongsTwo etc and the return is just giving you the top level

Comment: @OliverBS I pasted it in this pastebin http://pastebin.com/VBULxC3C

Comment: What is actually using the method get ?

Answer (score 1):

Robert

```
User::find(1);

find($id, $columns = "*")
{
  $user = User::get($columns, get_called_class(), PDO::FETCH_CLASS);
  return $user;
```

In your call to find you are passing 1 which I guess is `$id` but in the get you are passing `$columns` which means to me you are not passing `$id`

In summary, to me it looks like you are passing 1 but not doing anything with it ?

Let me know if this fixes it ?

Comment: The 1 is indeed `$id` but this doesn't solve the problem as I am currently using the `User::find()` method to get all the rows from the database. This method should have this line `return User::where('id=$id')->get(stuff)`